# Dynamic class in react.js

Tags: reactjs

All:

I wonder if I made a signin/signup toggle tab component, how can I dynamically add a selected class to according component(like ngclass)?

```
render(){
return (
            <div>
                <span className="tab" className={{"selected": this.state.signin}}>Sign In</span>
                <span className="tab" className={{"selected": !this.state.signin}}>Sign Up</span>
            </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: You are on the right track. Remember that class names have to be strings, so `className={this.state.signin ? 'selected' : ''}` would be more appropriate.

Comment: It also just came to my mind that you can do precisely this using [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) lib. Give it a try, it allows you to manipulate plain-objects with boolean values in order to apply classes.

Comment: @RishatMuhametshin in that way, I can not keep "tab" class, how can I merge them?

Comment: I would recommend you use the library `classnames` it is a very nice and useful tool. usage `import cx from 'classnames';` ....`<span className={cx('tab', {selected: this.state.signin})}>Sign In</span>`

Comment: @JohnRuddell Thanks, I chose that way at last.

Comment: @kuan awesome! I've used it for a few years now and absolutely love it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend you use the library [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) it is a very nice and useful tool.

usage

```
import cx from 'classnames';
...
<span className={cx('tab', {selected: this.state.signin})}>Sign In</span>
```

when invoking the function you can pass default values and an object to conditionally add classes in any order.

```
syntax: cx(default, {conditional: boolean, conditional: boolean});
syntax: cx({conditional: boolean, conditional: boolean}, default);
syntax: cx(something, {conditional: boolean}, 'something', 'something');
```

I prefer to use it consistently in the order of default string, conditionals. just for the sake of readability for me and others that come by, its easy when you expect it to be the same.

you can pass it a lot of different things and it handles it. From the NPM docs

```
classNames('foo', 'bar'); // => 'foo bar' 
classNames('foo', { bar: true }); // => 'foo bar' 
classNames({ 'foo-bar': true }); // => 'foo-bar' 
classNames({ 'foo-bar': false }); // => '' 
classNames({ foo: true }, { bar: true }); // => 'foo bar' 
classNames({ foo: true, bar: true }); // => 'foo bar' 

// lots of arguments of various types 
classNames('foo', { bar: true, duck: false }, 'baz', { quux: true }); // => 'foo bar baz quux' 

// other falsy values are just ignored 
classNames(null, false, 'bar', undefined, 0, 1, { baz: null }, ''); // => 'bar 1'
```

Comment: IMHO That's a lazy solution. dynamic classes is just an easy code write, you shouldn't need to import more libs.

Comment: @Despertaweb It depends on how complicated the classnames you need... now does that mean you have to? no, if it doesn't suite your needs then it doesn't make sense to use it. There was already an answer (this is also 5 years ago...) with a solution to the OP's question. It felt more appropriate to provide an alternative solution to give this question different types of answers so it can be viewed more holistically. As another data point, this package and others like it are more or less an industry standard today. `classnames` has ~8.5mil weekly downloads. `clsx` is at ~5.6mil weekly downloads

Comment: I see your point @John Ruddel, but as long as you could us "external" functions or even computed.... But of course is up to you hehe

Comment: Well at some point it doesn't make sense to re-invent the wheel. There are some places where writing everything from scratch makes sense, and other places where it doesn't. If someone wants to look at the source code from `classnames` even, to get inspiration and then write their own class name generator... have at it. But downvoting an old answer for the sake of writing it yourself isn't always the right approach either. Why not write your own router vs using a package? We should embrace open-source and help add to the community. Thats what this answer attempts to do :)

Comment: I see your point, but comparing writting a router vs a computed property AKA ClassName.... not same complexity, right?

Comment: An argument of complexity doesn't always mean its valid. Writing something from scratch can take time to nail out any unforseen issues or strange behavior where as a package that has been around for years with lots of usage, bug fixes... etc renders it quite useful from the get go. Again, if you want to write your own solution feel free to but this is more or less an industry standard, especially looking at its usage. Also in all of the answers i've provided this is one of maybe a handful that recommend a package. Hardly do it except when it seems useful. You do you though :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use template literals ``

In your case it will look like that:

```
<span className={`tab ${this.state.signin ? "selected" : ""}`}>Sign In</span>
```

Comment: thing I dont like about this is your class now looks like `"tab selected"` or when not selected `"tab "` notice the extra space. you can trim it but thats annoying to do every time you have a conditional class.

Comment: DOM parser doesn't care if you have trailing spaces in the `class` attribute or not. You generally shouldn't worry about this at all.

Answer (score 0):

Though John's answer does the Job. That library lacks function support for determining the value.

You can use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamic-class-list) npm package. It handles everything and has options for static and dynamic classes based on a variable or a function.

```
// Support for string arguments
getClassNames('class1', 'class2');

// support for Object
getClassNames({class1: true, class2 : false});

// support for all type of data
getClassNames('class1', 'class2', ['class3', 'class4'], { 
    class5 : function() { return false; },
    class6 : function() { return true; }
});

<div className={getClassNames({class1: true, class2 : false})} />
```